# Splice an object from an array in react usestate

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have an array of objects containing a list of items. The items are updated from a dynamic form field. Below is the item object

```
{ product_id: { name: "", price: 0, hsn: "" }, quantity: 0, cgst_amount: 0, sgst_amount: 0, igst_amount: 0, total: 0 }Ï
```

When I want to delete the unwanted item from the dynamic form I use the splice method to remove the object in the given index. This removes the correct object from the array but on the UI part, it will always remove the last item shown in the UI rather than removing the deleted object in the array.

This is my items array

```
const [items, setItems] = useState(quotation.items ? quotation.items : []);
```

Here is the form

```
        <div className="items-container mt-2">
          {items?.map((item, index) => (<div className="items">
            <div className="item-close">
              <div className="item-close-icon" onClick={() => closeItem(index)}>
                {items.length > 1 ? <Icon as={FaTimes} color="red.500" size="1.5em" /> : ""}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-field-two">
              <div className="card-field">
                <FormLabel htmlFor="item-name">Item</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="Item" defaultValue={item.product_id.name} disabled={!isEdit} />
              </div>
              <div className="card-field">
                <FormLabel htmlFor="item-quantity">Quantity</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="Quantity" defaultValue={item.quantity} disabled={!isEdit} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-field-two">
              <div className="card-field">
                <FormLabel htmlFor="item-rate">Price</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="Price" defaultValue={item.product_id.price} disabled={true} />
              </div>
              <div className="card-field">
                <FormLabel htmlFor="hsn">HSN</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="HSN" defaultValue={item.product_id.hsn} disabled={!isEdit} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-field-two">
              <div className="card-field">
                <FormLabel htmlFor="cgst">CGST</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="CGST" defaultValue={item.cgst_amount} disabled={true} />
              </div>
              <div className="card-field">
                <FormLabel htmlFor="sgst">SGST</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="SGST" defaultValue={item.sgst_amount} disabled={true} />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="card-field-two">
              <div className="card-field">
                <FormLabel htmlFor="igst">IGST</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="IGST" defaultValue={item.igst_amount} disabled={true} />
              </div>
              <div className="card-field">
                <FormLabel htmlFor="total">Total</FormLabel>
                <Input placeholder="Total" defaultValue={item.total_amount} disabled={true} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>))}
          <button className="add-item-btn orange-btn" disabled={!isEdit} onClick={() => setItems([...items, { product_id: { name: "", price: 0, hsn: "" }, quantity: 0, cgst_amount: 0, sgst_amount: 0, igst_amount: 0, total: 0 }])}>Add Item</button>
        </div>
```

Here is the close function to remove the items

```
const closeItem = (index) => {
  let itemsArray = [...items];
  itemsArray.splice(index, 1);
  let newArray = [...itemsArray]
  setItems(newArray);
}
```

Comment: i think it's your slice that made that issue. to delete something it's easier to use some id on your data rather than map function index number. then you could use filter method than slide

Comment: Giorgi Moniava Thank you it solved the issue. Sure I have accepted the answer.

Comment: @Romylussone Thank you. The issue was I forgot to put a unique key while looping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't manually provide a key to array elements, react defaults to using index as key, which may cause problems if array elements may [reorder](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys):

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may
> change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues
> with component state. Check out Robin Pokorny’s article for an
> in-depth explanation on the negative impacts of using an index as a
> key. If you choose not to assign an explicit key to list items then
> React will default to using indexes as keys.

Answer (score 0):

i had this problem, but i could fixed it. i use somcode like this :

```
setItems((items) => [...items, input].filter((item) => item.title != null));
```

you can use this :

```
setItems((items) => [...items, newArray].filter(item => item.product_id != null));
```

or :

```
    setItems((items) => [...items, newArray]);
```

I hope this will help the programmer :)